# Apex Web Services Trailhead

Tags: apex, rest-api, webservices, trailhead

I am doing a trailhead Apex Web Services: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_integration_services/units/apex_integration_webservices

When I follow the tutorial at the part Apex REST Walkthrough I created the class CaseManager logged into workbench and try to make a case with the URI /services/apexrest/Cases/
I get the error:

```
Service not found at: /services/apexrest/Cases/
```

Why is this? With The Rest API tutorial I had no Issues

Comment: In case you've `namespace` enabled then add it in your request like this: `/services/apexrest/your_namespace/Cases/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This URL works fine - [`/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Case`](http:///services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Case)

Comment: Thanks! for the answer tried that with cases 1 s too much

Comment: @Rahul If I would do a get wouldnt  my uri be: /services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Case/5000Y00000KpzCUQAZ     ???

Comment: I did not answer it, but yes that should be it. Best way to know is to check from [Salesforce workbench's](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php) rest explorer.